# Ajax post request

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Soy nuevo en `JS` y estoy confundido en esto, `post request` mediante `AJAX`, querría saber si están bien mis comentarios y si estoy en lo correcto porque me confundo bastante, se abre un `post request` y se le pasa 3 argumentos, `string` que contenga la `url` a la que se hace la petición, se le pasa data que son mis valores de mi formulario gracias a `serialize()` y se guarda en data, ¿es obligatorio? hay que darle estas dos cosas para que luego me retorne no? me retornara **success** que es una función le paso un parámetro cualquiera, ¿en este caso datos corresponden a data? (información que rellene en los campos en forma de **string**). Así luego puedo hacer **datos.saludo** y me dará lo que necesito que es la respuesta, ¿es así?.¿Sabe alguien algún sitio con buena explicación de lo que busco? Mil gracias

```js
$("form").on("submit", function( event ) { // Porque es on('submit') ???

alert( $( this ).serialize() ) // Crea una string de los elementos del formulario(form object)

event.preventDefault(); // evitar lo que pasaría por default así puedo enviar po ajax ???

// 1. open ajax request post (url im requesting / data from form(serializing) / datos que le pasare)
$.post({
  //2. STRING que contenga la url a la que se hace la petición => JSON => {"saludo":"\u00a1Hola !, vengo desde el servidor.","teléfono":"Tu tel\u00e9fono es el ","horario":"No te llamaremos si no es en horario de ","apunte":"\u00a1Una pena que tengas tan poca satisfacci\u00f3n!"}
  url:'http://cosasdigitales.com/documentacion/validarFormulario.php',
  //3. OBJETO puro o STRING que es enviado al servidor para la peticion(campoNombre=fran&campoTelefono=61999&horario=ma%C3%B1anas&satisfaccion=10&politica=on)
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  //4. FUNCIÓN que retorna la información, la respuesta de ajax (le paso lo que sea, datos sera mi objeto y saludo mi propiedad => datos.saludo), 'success' = KEYWORD!
  //RESPUESTA => ¡Hola fran!, vengo desde el servidor.<br>Tu teléfono es el 61999<br>No te llamaremos si no es en horario de mañanas<br>¡Una pena que tengas tan poca satisfacción!
  success: function(datos) {
    let texto = datos.saludo + '<br>' + datos.telefono + '<br>' + datos.horario + '<br>' + datos.apunte;
    msg(texto, 1);
    console.log(texto);
  }
});
});


function msg(mensajes, tiempo) {

  $('#mensaje').html(mensajes);

  $('#alertas').addClass('visibles');

  setTimeout( function(){
    $('#alertas').removeClass('visibles');
  },tiempo * 1000);
}
```

```css
        body {
            background: #F2F3EB;
            font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        h1 {
            color: #474544;
            font-size: 32px;
            font-weight: 700;
            letter-spacing: 7px;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        h4 {
            margin: 36px 0 10px;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            font-weight: lighter;
        }
        h4:first-of-type {
            margin: 0 0 10px;
        }
        .underline {
            border-bottom: solid 2px #474544;
            margin: 0 auto 10px;
            width: 80px;
        }
        form {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        fieldset {
            width: calc(48% - 9px);
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            padding: 5px 20px;
            margin: 0 12px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        main {
            border: solid 3px #474544;
            max-width: 768px;
            margin: 60px auto;
            position: relative;
        }
        main *,
        main *:before,
        main *:after {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        select {
            width: 100%;
            border: 2px solid #555;
            padding: 10px;
            background: transparent;
        }
        input[type=text],
        input[type=submit],
        input[type=password],
        input[type=range],
        textarea {
            background: none;
            border: none;
            border-bottom: solid 2px #474544;
            color: #474544;
            font-size: 1.000em;
            font-weight: 400;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            margin: 0em 0 1.875em 0;
            padding: 0 0 0.875em 0;
            text-transform: none;
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
            -o-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
            -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
            -o-transition: all 0.3s;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }
        input[type=text],
        input[type=submit],
        input[type=password],
        input[type=range],
        textarea {
            -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
        }
        input[type=text]:active,
        input[type=text]:focus,
        input[type=password]:active,
        input[type=password]:focus,
        textarea:active,
        textarea:focus {
            outline: none;
            padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
        }
        input[type=range] {
            border: none;
            margin-top: 10px
        }
        textarea {
            height: 85px;
        }
        input[type=submit] {
            background-color: #474544;
            border-top: 2px solid #F2F3EB;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #F2F3EB;
            color: #F2F3EB;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            padding: 10px 18px;
            margin-top: 25px
        }
        input[type=submit]:hover {
            background-color: #F2F3EB;
            border-top: 2px solid #474544;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #474544;
            color: #474544;
        }
        label {
            color: #555;
            display: block;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        fieldset:nth-child(6) label {
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
            padding: 5px;
            display: block;
        }
        form > span {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 52px;
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 39px;
            font-weight: 00;
            border-bottom: 2px dashed #555;
            padding-bottom: 29px;
        }

        form > label {
            text-align: center;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 20px 0 0px;
        }
        .error {
            border-bottom: 2px dashed red !important;
        }
        #alertas {
            background: grey;
            position: fixed;
            top: 100px;
            right: 0;
            transition: all .5s;
            transform: translateX(100%);
        }
        #alertas.visibles{
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
        #mensaje {
    padding: 12px 10px;
    border: 2px dashed #F2F3EB;
    margin: 10px 35px;
    color: #F2F3EB;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
 <title>Formulario Javascript</title>
 <meta charset="UTF8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <main>
  <div>
   <form action="gestor.php" method="POST">

    <h1>&bull; ¿Hablamos? &bull;</h1>
    <div class="underline"></div>
    <span>&#9743;</span>

    <fieldset>

     <label>Nombre:
      <input type="text" id="campoNombre" name="campoNombre">
     </label>
     <label>Teléfono:
      <input type="text" id="campoTelefono" name="campoTelefono">
     </label>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>

     <h4>Horario de contacto</h4>
     <label>
      <input type="radio" name="horario" value="mañanas">Mañanas
     </label>
     <label>
      <input type="radio" name="horario" value="tardes">Tardes
     </label>
     <label>
      <input type="radio" name="horario" value="indiferente">Indiferente
     </label>

     <h4>Nivel de satisfacción con la aplicación</h4>
     <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="satisfaccion" name="satisfaccion">

    </fieldset>

    <label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="politica" name="politica"> Acepto la política de datos
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar con AJAX">

    <p class="respuesta"></p>

   </form>
  </div>
  <div id="alertas">
   <p id="mensaje">Enviar con AJAX</p>
  </div>
 </main>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Vamos a explicar `post` según la documentación de jQuery:

> Descripción: carga datos desde el servidor usando una solicitud HTTP
>   POST.

Estos son los parámetros, explicados, que puede tener una petición POST:

> - `url`
>
>   Tipo: String
>
>   Una cadena que contiene la URL a la que se envía la solicitud.
> - `data`
>
>   Tipo: PlainObject o String
>
>   Un objeto simple o cadena que se envía al servidor con la solicitud.
> - `success`
>
>   Tipo: Función (datos de PlainObject, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR)
>
>   Una función de devolución de llamada que se ejecuta si la solicitud
>     tiene éxito. Obligatorio si se proporciona `dataType`, pero puede ser
>     nulo en ese caso.
> - `dataType`
>
>   Tipo: Cadena
>
>   El tipo de datos esperados del servidor.
>
>   Valor predeterminado: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text,
>     html).
>
> <sub>[`post` en la documentación de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)</sub>

---

### Observaciones

Desde jQuery 3, `success` se considera obsoleto. Se recomienda usar `done`.

---

### Ejemplo de una petición

#### HTML (formulario)

```
    <form action="archivo.php" method="post" id="idFormulario">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
            <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="msg">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
```

---

#### jQuery/Javascript

```
        var frm=$( "#idFormulario" ); //Identificamos el formulario por su id
        var datos = frm.serialize();  //Serializamos sus datos

        //Preparamos la petición Ajax
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: frm.prop("action"),    //Leerá la url en la etiqueta action del formulario (archivo.php)
            method: frm.prop('method'), //Leerá el método en etiqueta method del formulario
            data: datos,                //Variable serializada más arriba 
            dataType: "json"            //puede ser de otro tipo
        });

        //Este bloque se ejecutará si no hay error en la petición
        request.done(function(respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta);
            console.log(respuesta.foo); //foo es una propiedad (clave), del json que devuelve el servidor
            //Tratamos a respuesta según sea el tipo  y la estructura               
        });

        //Este bloque se ejecuta si hay un error
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Hubo un error: " + textStatus);
        });
```

---

#### PHP (archivo.php)

El servidor responde con un objeto JSON, que es manejado en el `done` de la petición Ajax:

```
<?php

    $arrRespuesta = array(
        "foo" => "valor de bar",
        "bar" => "valor de foo",
    );

    echo json_encode($arrRespuesta);

?>
```

Comment: El OP quiere aclarar las dudas de $.post() no de $.ajax(), no son diferentes los parámetros, etc?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez [mira esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/126120/29967) y los comentarios. Su duda en realidad es sobre una petición post usando Ajax.

Answer (score 3):

para hacer una petición con ajax, es de la siguiente manera:

```
//se utiliza $.ajax(), a la cual se le pasa un objeto {}, con la información
$.ajax({
    type:"POST", // la variable type guarda el tipo de la peticion GET,POST,..
    url:"http://ruta", //url guarda la ruta hacia donde se hace la peticion
    data:{nombre:"pepe",edad:10}, // data recive un objeto con la informacion que se enviara al servidor
    success:function(datos){ //success es una funcion que se utiliza si el servidor retorna informacion
         console.log(datos.promedio)
     },
    dataType: dataType // El tipo de datos esperados del servidor. Valor predeterminado: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).
})
```

- La variable `data` es opcional utilizarla, puede ser el caso de que agas una peticion al servidor, y no envies datos , pero si los recivas o no.
- La función `success` igual puede que no la utilices, es opcional, el caso seria que realices una petición al servidor donde envíes datos, pero no recibas información del mismo.

mas informacion: *https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/*